# How to avoiding flicker during redirection while using ui-routing?

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have the following code inside app.run method. The state is being changed to login but with a flicker. How can I avoid this flicker?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toStateParams) {
    if (toState.name != 'login') {
        $rootScope.toState = toState;
        $rootScope.toStateParams = toStateParams;
        //Checking whether the user is logged, if not redirect to login page.
        if (!principal.isIdentityResolved()) {
            $state.go('login');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```